# Program can't find discord.py despite it being installed. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I know there are questions like this on here already but none of the answers actually worked.  I use the command `pip install discord` , it installs successfully, I hop onto my program (Very basic bot stuff. I'm new to this) run it, and it can't find the discord module. I know it's installed, I just don't why it can't find it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\myuser\OneDrive\Desktop\bot.py", line 4, in <module>
import discord.abc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

that's the exact error message if needed.

Comment: if you have multiple versions of Python installed makes sure pip installs it for the version you're using. How are you running this file?

Comment: @Ethicist I am using python version 3.10.7 running right from the IDE.

Comment: What's the exact command that runs when your IDE tries executing your file?

Comment: If your IDE runs python files using `python path/to/file.p`" try getting the executable's path (the one you can access through the PATH variable) and run `path/to/executable -m pip install discord`

Comment: Sorry, I'm an absolute idiot when it comes to this stuff. wdym by "trying to get the executables path"?

Comment: if you're on windows run `where python` to get the executable's path (if when you run files you see e.g `python -u "yourfile.py"` in the terminal) and take that filepath, assuming it's `path/to/python.exe` you would run `path/to/python.exe -m pip install discord`

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
pip install discord.py
```